# priority queue, where to insert?

Tags: c

so I am having trouble implementing priority queue. For a priority queue, I need to find the first place where it is empty...that's where the element go, we will swap later..but I am having trouble figuring out the algorithm to find it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
void pq_insert(struct tnode* p)
{
    struct tnode* curr=NULL;
    struct tnode* prev=NULL;
   printf("inserting:%c,%f\n",p->symbol,p->freq);
   if(qhead==NULL) /*qhead is null*/
   {
    qhead = p;
        /*TODO: write code to insert when queue is empty*/
   }
   /*TODO: write code to find correct position to insert*/
    curr = qhead;
    while (curr != NULL){//I think this is wrong
        if ((curr -> left) == NULL){
            curr = curr -> right;
        }
        else{
            curr = curr -> left;
        }   
    }

   if(curr==qhead)
   {
        /*TODO: write code to insert before the current start*/

   }
   else /*insert between prev and next*/
   {
        /*TODO: write code to insert in between*/
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the code you think is wrong:

```
while (curr != NULL){//I think this is wrong
    if ((curr -> left) == NULL){
        curr = curr -> right;
    }
    else{
        curr = curr -> left;
    }   
}
```

is wrong.  You are navigating curr to some part of your tree regardless of your current node.

You probably want to change your inner if to something like:

```
if (p->freq < curr->freq)
```

Comment: i think im just finding the first empty node thats closest to the root and most far left. I dont think the freq actually matters?

Comment: Isn't this a priority queue?  If you don't keep the list sorted, when you get an item you are going to have to examine every item to find the correct element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are doing with this while-loop.

```
while (curr != NULL){//I think this is wrong
    if ((curr -> left) == NULL){
        curr = curr -> right; // Why to go right here?!, isn't this an empty node?
    }
    else{
        curr = curr -> left;
    }   
}
```

If I am looking for the nearest empty (NULL) left node, I will do this

```
while (curr != NULL){
    if ((curr -> left) == NULL){//The left node is NULL. Great, I found empty node.
        curr = NULL;
    }
    else{ //hmmm, left node is not empty. Lets go left for more nodes. 
        curr = curr -> left;
    }   
}
```

But like this, searching will be going left-only. after some inserts the tree will not be balanced.

If you give more details, it will be more clear.